# Use external library in pandas_udf in PySpark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, valueerror

It's possible to use a external library like [textdistance](https://pypi.org/project/textdistance/) inside `pandas_udf`? I have tried and I get this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I have tried with Spark version 2.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can package the `textdistance` together with your own code (use setup.py and `bdist_egg` to build an `egg` file), and specify the final package with option `--py-files` while you run spark.

btw, the error message doesn't seem to relate with `textdistance` at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Spark UDF, for example to implement the Ratcliff-Obershelp function:

```
import textdistance

def my_ro(s1,s2):
  d = textdistance.ratcliff_obershelp(s1,s2)
  return d

spark.udf.register("my_ro", my_ro, FloatType())

spark.sql("SELECT word1, word2, my_ro(word1,word2) as ro FROM spark_df")\
.show(100,False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `pandas_udf`, you would first need to create a dataframe out of several passed `pd.Series` objects. Then, pass columns to the function using `lambda`.

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T
import pandas as pd
import textdistance

df = spark.createDataFrame([('abc', 'ab'), ('def','f')], ['word1', 'word2'])

@F.pandas_udf(T.DoubleType())
def my_func(s1: pd.Series, s2: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
    return df.apply(lambda x: textdistance.ratcliff_obershelp(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)

df.withColumn('new_col', my_func('word1', 'word2')).show()
# +-----+-----+-------+
# |word1|word2|new_col|
# +-----+-----+-------+
# |  abc|   ab|    0.8|
# |  def|    f|    0.5|
# +-----+-----+-------+
```